# Как нарисовать гистограмму из списка, содержащего готовую гистограмму?

Tags: python-3.x, гистограммы

При этом список представляет из себя не сырые данные, а уже готовую гистограмму, которую нужно просто нарисовать.

Например, есть список `s = [1, 2, 1, 5]`.

Нужно нарисовать гистограмму: первый столбец высотой `1`, второй столбец высотой `2`, третий столбец высоты `1` и 4 столбец высоты `5`.

Кол-во столбцов должно быть равно длине списка – `len(s)`.

Comment: Уже пробовали сделать это с помощью какого-то графического пакета?

Comment: Искал такую возможность в matplotlib.pyplot, но так и не нашёл... В matplotlib.pyplot гистограммы рисуются из сырых данных.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, речь все же о столбиковой диаграмме (bar plot) или о [гистограмме](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего использовать [pyplot.bar](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar). Первым параметром передается последовательность `x` - координат столбцов, вторым - последовательность их высот.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = [1, 2, 1, 5]
x = range(len(s))
ax = plt.gca()
ax.bar(x, s, align='edge') # align='edge' - выравнивание по границе, а не по центру
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'))
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram]

Comment: Спасибо!
И ещё вопрос. Как сделать, чтобы прямоугольники были не по центру значений на оси x, а справа от этих значений?
А ещё, как подписать на оси x каждый прямоугольник?

Comment: @immelnikoff, обновил ответ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!